# Merge and sync MS SQL server database

Tags: database, sql-server-2005

I have couple of kiosks running at client's location which access an online MS SQL server 2005 to process data, but the internet connectivity is unreliable. I am fine with installing SQL server on the kiosk itself and sync it once a week to the central server. Since there are lots of kiosks, it needs to be a merged sync. 
Any better ideas for caching?
What are the tools for merge sync?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for replication. Replication is a set of technologies for copying and distributing data and database objects from one database to another and then synchronizing between databases to maintain consistency. Using replication, you can distribute data to different locations and to remote or mobile users over local and wide area networks, dial-up connections, wireless connections, and the Internet.

Here is a replication overview: http://technet.microsoft.com/library/ms166367.aspx

Comment: thanks, is there a way to run a small footprint sql server as i want to run it on a Intel atom machine with 1 gb ram

Comment: what is the technology used to make sure the reads and write to the online server are buffered from the offline server once when the internet connection is re-established. this is to handle internet faults and errors.